# How do I make a Google Presentation appear on the projector display?

Tags: nvidia, google-chrome, webapps

When I click the Start Presentation button in a Google presentation in Google Docs, the full-screen presentation appears on my laptop display instead of the display of the TV or projector I'm connected to in a meeting room.

It occasionally does appear in a window with a titlebar, and with that I would be able to drag and drop that window onto the other display, but I can't reproduce this behaviour on demand. It seems to be random!

I am using KDE, Google Chrome and NVidia drivers (nouveau doesn't support my graphics chipset.) I have a dual monitor setup with Xinerama normally (and the configuration never auto-adjusts nor can it be auto-adjusted, so that's what I'm using in the meeting room as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Firefox. This is an issue only with Chrome.

Once again, I've found that a Google product works better on Firefox than on Chrome. Go figure!